# Get any id to any user exists in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite3-ruby

I am new to rails and have a task that asks me to send an invitation for any user to be admin in my magazine here is my piece of code

```
def invite
    inviteUser = { 'user_id' => current_user.id, 'Magazine_id' => params[:id] }
    CollaborationInvitation.create(inviteUser)
    @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :back
    rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

I need to replace `current_user.id` with something that refers to any user's id which exists in my database to send him an invitation to be admin with me I tried to add `@User=Users.All` and then pass it as a variable but it got me an error I tried a lot of things but every time I get an error except for adding `current_user.id`

**ps: I am using devise for authentication**

Comment: It should be `@users = User.all` which will return you all the users in table, try `@user = User.last`. Or you can also loop through all the users and send invite to all `User.all.each do |user|  ..do your logic here wth the user.. end`

Comment: @Sontya I don't need to send to all users I just need to send to a one user by inserting his id

Comment: then do it, `User.last.id` will give you last user in database or `User.first.id` will give you first user in database

Answer (score 4):

You asked a couple things, and it is kind of confusing what you want to do.

Here is how you get all ids of records in a model.

**Rails4:** `User.ids`

**Rails3:** `User.all.map(&:id)`

Or (not sure if `#pluck` is in Rails 3 or not)

```
User.pluck(:id)
```

If you want to get a random user (you mentioned "any user") you could do.

```
User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample)
```

Though I think what you really want to do is to pass the id or some other attribute of a user as a param to the action and send that user an invitation.

Presumably you either have a post or get route for `"users#invite"` (the action you wrote in your question). You can add a named parameter there or you can pass a url param or if you are using a post route, you could add the param to the post body.

Then in your contoller you can do something like this (I'll use email as an attribute):

```
def invite
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user_email])

  #Rails 3 like this
  # @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user_email])
   # now do stuff with user
end
```

Comment: I used User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample) with id 18 which exists in the database it didn't raise any error but It didn't send it to the user with the id 18

Comment: :id is the symbol. If you already know the id you can just do User.find(18)

Comment: Here is the documentation for pluck http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck. Basically, it returns an array of the values of the attributes passed. Then Array#sample picks a random item in the array. So basically `User.find(User.pluck(:id).sample)` means find the first User where user.id is equal to a random id from a list of all user ids.

Answer (score 3):

User.all will return you the collection of users. So,
Find the user object to get an id...
Try this code....

```
def invite
     inviteUser = { 'user_id' => User.find_by_email('user@example.com').id, 'Magazine_id' => params[:id] }
     CollaborationInvitation.create(inviteUser)
     @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:id])
     redirect_to :back
     rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
     redirect_to root_path
 end
```

Comment: this sends to a single user I listed all users so I can send the invitation to any user I need just by clicking on invite link but this always sends to a single user and I need to make it user friendly  ` <%= u.firstname%> <%=link_to'<span class="label label-primary" style="cursor:pointer">Invite</span>'.html_safe ,
  controller: :magazines, action: :invite, method: :put, u_id: u.id %> `

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
User.last.id
```

or

```
User.find_by_email("xyz@test.com").id
```

or

```
User.where(email: "xyz@test.com").first.id
```

Replace xyz@test.com with desired user email address. To get more details on rails active record query interface, please read rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html